# Stream c++ file on web-Browser

Tags: c++, stream, browser, push

I have a c++ project (server-side) which sends the data to the client side with the help of event source. Now for debugging purposes I have maintained a trace file (text). On all the critical areas in the c++ code where there is a fear of code-break, I have added a line which writes the "success" text to this trace file. It works fine. I can know where the code is success and where it failed.

But I am on the server side. I want to avail this facility to the client too. However, I am unsure about how to do that? Should I stream the file on web-browser, or is there any other way I can send the data "live" to web-browser?

I checked this link, however, I am not sure if I can use this. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

your question is a bit confusing, and without any sample of your code it is a bit unclear of what you want to do. however, the best suggestion i can give is to do this:

1. Store the text document on a server of your choice.
2. write a program to contact the server and download the data. (Using Winsock.h)

OR

Directly send the file to the computer. you'll have to write a program to contact the server at which point B is located.

for information on writing an application using Winsock.h, check here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629(v=vs.85).aspx

if you really must store the data live in a web browser, then take a look at Java or VisualBasic, as both are heavily supported in all web browsers, while C++ is not.

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I understand you correctly.  You want to send success / failure of the webserver to your client program?

Well, that's part of the job of a webserver, as dictated by the http protocol.  A webserver will respond to a client request with a response header, followed by the requested page (if it exists as a valid resource on the server).

For more information on http response headers have a look at [this article](http://djce.org.uk/dumprequest), or [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Response_message), which both detail the request / response conversation between browser and webserver.

Hope this helps.